# Visual Studio debugger is not loading the correct binaries

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I am trying to debug my application. I have already installed that product in my machine. I am putting the debug points in particular entry points. But is throwing one warning, The breakpoints will not currently be hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem do the following steps:
1. Open your solution in Visual Studio
2. Start debug your application 
3. Select Debug Menu -> Windows -> Select Modules (Here you can check, which of the binary version your code is pointing. 
4. Open Project Properties -> Application -> Click on Assembly Information
5. Increase the Assembly version details 
6. Click Ok

This will fix your problem and you will be able to debug your application.

Comment: Hi Suresh, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer, that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :)